# How to calculate product of a lot of numbers?

Tags: c++

So I am a beginner in c++ programming and I was doing some problem online. 
I have to calculate all the products of numbers from 999 to 100 (Eg.999*999 , 999*998 ... 800* 800 , 800 *799 ... , 100 * 100). I can easily print out these products but when I try to pass these values to a function they do not work. 
Can you please look at the following code and point out anything that's wrong?
I think its got something to do with buffer but I have no idea how to fix that. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

unsigned long int num,rev,temp,rem = 0,reversed = 0;
int ispalin(unsigned long int n)
{
    temp=n;
    while(temp!=0)
    {
        rem = temp%10;
        reversed = reversed*10 + rem;
        temp/=10;
    }   
   if(reversed == n)
   {
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int maxi = 0;
    for (int i =999 ; i >= 100;i--)
    {
        for(int j = i;j >= 100; j--)
        {
            rev = ispalin(i*j);
            if (rev == 1)
            {
                if(i*j > maxi)
                {
                    maxi = i*j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<maxi<<" This is max"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `//Checks stuff here return 1 if true 0 if flase` Why not just return [`true` or `false`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/bool)?

Comment: I have never used Boolean values in c++ and I do not know how to use them. I dont think that changing that will make a difference. Will it?

Comment: What is not working, exactly?

Comment: Did you try to change the datatype of `i`, `j` and `maxi` to `unsigned long int`?  I think it could make the magic.

Comment: No it will not. But you should use `bool` when it semantically returns true/false. Also you can just write `if (ispalin(i*j))`.

Comment: @zenith thanks for the help I shall look up bool and use them from now on.
CrApHeR Did that no change. 
SergiyMigdalskiy the program always return 0 when it should return ateast 1 palindromic number.

Comment: Maybe `ispalin` never returns 1 and that's why `maxi` stays 0? We cannot know, since you chose not to show us everything.

Comment: It was a simple checkpalindrome() function which worked for values like 99999 so I thought i might leave it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reversed` must be reset to zero at the beginning of every check for palindrome. The best would be to make `reversed` (and others) a local variable of `ispalin`.

Comment: You got me thanks a lot! That was silly of me to not do that!

Comment: Also, the best is not to use globals when they aren't absolutely necessary - this is one great example of why...